# HTML buttons of type submit in forms do not work

Tags: html, jsp

I have a problem with my application. I have developed an application using Java, JSP, Servlets, html etc.

All of a sudden all my buttons of type submit do not work. I have tested my application yesterday and it worked absolutely fine! Today when I wanted to retest and make some changes all the submit buttons do not work. 
(I tried to open the app in IE, CHROME, FIREFOX and it doesn;t work).

.jsp page

```
<body>
<form class="container">
<form id="search_form" class="form-horizontal" name="profile"    action="UserController" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">

    <%--<form class="container">--%>
        <h2>Employee Management <img src="http://seeklogo.com/images/S/salon-logo-F0E41E42DD-seeklogo.com.gif" style="float: right; height: 50px; width: 50px"></h2>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Appointments</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>APPOINTMENTS</h3>
            <div class="table-striped">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead style="background-color: lightblue">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee ID</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Start hour</th>
                        <th>End hour</th>
                        <th>Approve</th>
                        <th>Decline</th>
                        <th>Remove</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <c:forEach var="appointment_item" items="${appointments}">
                        <tr><td>
                            <c:out value="${appointment_item.employee_id}"></c:out>
                        </td>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${appointment_item.date}"></c:out>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${appointment_item.hour_start}"></c:out>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="${appointment_item.hour_end}"></c:out>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" name="approve_app" value="<c:out value="${appointment_item.id}"></c:out>" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Approve
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" name="decline_app" value="<c:out value="${appointment_item.id}"></c:out>" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Decline
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="submit" name="remove_app_e" value="<c:out value="${appointment_item.id}"></c:out>" class="btn btn-default">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot nest one `<form>` inside another `<form>`.

Comment: I will try now without one form but yesterday was ok :-?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I am very confused why it did work before but thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using duplicate Tag `<form>`
You can not using tag `<form>` in `<form>`

And Have 2 solution
1. Delete `<form class="container">`
2. Add `<form class="container" action="?" method="POST"></form>`